# Is this probability always positive?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose you have a random variable $X$ with a given probability distribution. You select an $iid$ sample of size $n$ from this distribution, namely, $x_1,\dots,x_n$. Can we say in general (even when $X$ can take infinitely many values or it is a continuous variable) that $$\Pr(\min\{x_1,\dots,x_n\} = \max\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}) > 0 \ ?$$

In other words, $\Pr(x_1=\dots=x_n) >0$. If no, then under what conditions the statement is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true if and only if there is some value $x$ such that $\Pr(X=x)>0$. In particular, it is true for any discrete variable or a continuous variable with an atom, but not for typical continuous variables.

To see this, if $\Pr(X=x)=p>0$ then the probability you want is at least $p^n$. If no such $x$ exists then $\Pr(X_2=X_1\mid X_1=x)=0$ for each $x$, so $\Pr(X_2=X_1\mid X_1)=0$, so $\Pr(X_2=X_1)=0$.

Comment: By **atom** do you mean a singleton? Just to make sure I completely understand it, by typical continuous variables you mean those with $\Pr(X=x) =0$ for any $x$? So the statement is never true for typical continuous variables?

Comment: Yes, the statement is never true for typical continuous variables which have a probability density function. But you can have a kind of hybrid between discrete and continuous, for example if $X$ measures the lifetime of a bulb where there is a small probability that it won't work at all owing to a manufacturing fault, but otherwise it lasts for time given by an exponential variable. This sort of thing is sometimes referred to as a continuous variable with an atom at $0$.

Comment: Yes. A probability distribution is a $\sigma$-finite measure, and "typical continuous variables" correspond to measures that are *absolutely continuous* with respect to Lebesgue measure.  See [Lebesgue decomposition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_decomposition_theorem) for how a probability measure splits as the sum of an absolutely continuous piece and a singular piece.  Your statement never holds for typical continuous variables.  Some singular measures are stranger than discrete probability measures, but what Especially Lime says above characterizes when your statement holds.